# What does the Docker sleep command do?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I can't find a clear explanation as to what the Docker sleep command does so can someone explain please? For example:

```
docker container run -d alpine sleep 1d
```

I have had a look online but I can't find a simple explanation.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a [`docker` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/); can you clarify what use you're asking about?

Comment: @DavidMaze I edited my question and put an example of how it is used.

Comment: That's not a docker command. That's just running the normal linux `sleep` command inside a container. Recall that the syntax of `docker run` is, broadly `docker run <image> <command>`, where by default `<command>` is simply passed to the shell.

Comment: @larsks ok great, I understand now thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ```
> docker container run -d --name mycontainer myimage:mytag sleep infinity
> ```

The last part after the image name  (i.e. `sleep infinity`) is not a docker command but a command sent to the container to override its default command (set in the `Dockerfile`).

An extract from the documentation (you can get it typing `man sleep` in your terminal, it may vary depending on the implementation)

> Pause for NUMBER seconds.  SUFFIX may be 's' for seconds (the default),
> 'm' for minutes, 'h' for hours or 'd' for days

To my surprise, the parameter `infinity` is not documented in my implementation but is still accepted. It's quite easy to understand: it pauses indefinitely (i.e. until the command is stopped/killed). In your own example above, it will pause for one day.

**What is the usual reason to use `sleep` as a command to run a docker container?**

A docker container will live until the command it runs finishes. This command is normally set in the `Dockerfile` used to build the image (in a `CMD` stanza) and can be overridden on the command line (as in the above examples).

A number of base images (like base OS for debian, ubuntu, centos....) will run a shell as the default command (`bash` or `sh` in general). If you try to spawn a container from that image using its default command, it will live until the shell exits.

When running such an image interactively (i.e. with `docker container run -it .....`), it will run until you end your shell session. But if you want to launch it in the background (i.e. with `docker container run -d ...`) it will exit immediately leaving you with a stopped container.

In this case, you can "fake" a long running service by overriding the default command with a long running command that basically does nothing but wait for the container to stop. Two widely used commands for this are `sleep infinity` (or whatever period suiting your needs) and `tail -f /dev/null`

After you launched a container like this you can use it to test whatever you need. The most common way is to run an interactive shell against it:

```
# command will depend on shells available in your image
docker exec -it mycontainer [bash|sh|zsh|ash|...]
```

Once you are done with your experimentation/test, you can stop and recycle your container

```
docker container stop mycontainer
docker container rm mycontainer
```